# Two functions equal in some point

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

I have two continuous functions $f,g$, $f(0) \lt g(0), f(1) \gt g(1)$. How do I prove without using "advanced" theorem (using only definitions of limit, continious functions and sup/inf definitions), that there is some $x \in (0,1)$, for which $f(x) = g(x)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

It's equivalent to showing that the function $h(x) = f(x) - g(x)$ has a root, i.e. a value $x$ for which $h(x) = 0$. Since $h(0) < 0$ and $h(1) > 0$, that should not be hard.

Comment: I have the proof which says that $sup {x \in [0,1] | h(x) \le 0}$ is the value, in which $h$ becomes zero. Problem is that proof doesn't use the fact that $h(0) \lt 0$ and $h(1) \gt 0$. Where are these facts used?

Comment: @DarkArchon The problem with that is that if there does not exist *any* $x$ for which $h(x) < 0$, then the value is a supremum of an empty set.

Comment: Is there a way to "fix" that proof?

Comment: @DarkArchon Yes. Using the fact that $h$ has both negative and positive values. Also, the statement you wrote is not quite correct. For example, if $h(x) = -1$ for all $x$, then the supremum of $\{x\in [0,1]: h(x)\leq 0\}$ is the supremum of $[0,1]$ which is $1$, but $h(1)\neq 0$.

Comment: @5xum: the statement follows from Intermediate Value Theorem, right? But is the OP allowed to use it?